# I want to calculate a total of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to calculate a total of amount of ng-repeat with the condition.

My table looks like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="Company in Companies track by $index">
  <td>Departmend</td>
  <td>Amount</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>HR</td>
  <td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>IT</td>
  <td>200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>HR</td>
  <td>600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2">Total:</td>
</tr>
```

My script like this.

```
<script>
     if ($scope.Department == "HR") {
         var Total = 0;
          angular.forEach($scope.Companies, function (item) { 
             Total = Math.abs(Total) + Math.abs(item.Amount);                                     
          });
      }

</script>
```

Comment: what is issue you are facing can you elaborate more

Comment: I'm not able to filter only the Department HR total

Comment: What is the condition? have you mad use of ng-repeat? Please update the question

Comment: The Condition is to Total only the Department = "HR" i'm not sure the way I wrote the the script is correct .

Comment: Please add the definition for `$scope.company` array.

Comment: I have added  ng-repeat="Company in Companies track by $index"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a solution like this? Finding the total of the array depending on its type?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.Companies = [
    { Amount: 200, Department: "HR" },
    { Amount: 300, Department: "IT" },
    { Amount: 400, Department: "HR" },
    { Amount: 500, Department: "IT" },
    { Amount: 600, Department: "HR" }
  ];
  $scope.totalValue = 0;
  angular.forEach($scope.Companies, function(item) {
    if (item.Department === "HR") {
      $scope.totalValue += Math.abs(item.Amount);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Departmend</td>
      <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="Company in Companies track by $index">
      <td>{{Company.Department}}</td>
      <td>{{Company.Amount}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>{{totalValue}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```